# jQuery Post PHP Value to PHP File and Proceed

Tags: php, jquery, post

i am using an upload script, allowing the use of the "data" value to post additional information to the "upload.php" file. The description is as following :

data    String, Function, Object    ''

If given as string is used for sending additional parameters in GET to the php script. If given as function must return a url formated string. This function is excecuted on the start upload event, so the data are created when Upload button is pressed. If given as object must have this format {getvar:value, anothergetvar:value....}. This is similar to jQuery Ajax data.

I've got the following Code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#uploader_div').ajaxupload({
url:'upload.php',
language: 'de_DE',
data: "<?php echo $_GET['id']?>"
});
</script>
```

In my Source code, the value is parsed correctly and spits out "55" which is right cause i am on customer-ID 55 profile page. Now i want to get the data value in the "upload.php" i used :

$data = $_GET['data']
   print_r($data)

and it doesnt return anything.

What can i do to get the value correct?

Comment: try $data = $_REQUEST['data'] ;

Comment: I'm against @Satya's recommendation on `$_REQUEST`. There are ways without that variable.

Comment: I am open to your suggestions Mauris , what I wrote is just one way, not the only way :)

Comment: If every field in your form is setup like this `name='data[id]'` then instead of passing the entire `$_REQUEST` array you can send just `$_REQUEST['data']`.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose $.ajaxupload works similar to $.ajax, which means that you send data in a wrong way.
It should be done like this:

```
data: {
    id: 13
}
```

And you can get get your data like this in the PHP script:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
```

Or with POST, if you use POST.